# How to init JS libraries within directive's controller

Tags: angularjs, plupload

I'm writing a directive to wrap plupload functionality.

The directive is intended to be used as you can see here: http://pastebin.com/sddR0UL7

Here (http://pastebin.com/c09LWeu4) you can find the template the directive reference.

And here's the directive's code (coffeescript): http://pastebin.com/SCwbkHWf

When visiting the page containing the directive I can see "Error: p is null" which
signifies that plupload could not be initialized (usually because references to
container is not defined).

Executing directive step by step I can see that the attributes it references are all
defined, so I think that the error is due to DOM not being compiled/linked yet.

How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the culprit.

It seems like plupload.init manipulates the DOM so initializing the component within
controller breaks the "don't manipulate DOM in controller" rule.

So, by movine the initialization of plupload into "link" function, everything works
as advertised.

Still I'm open for other advices or best practices.

Thanks